# Property not accessible even though declared public

Tags: c#, oop, properties, encapsulation

Here is my problem in `C#`:

I have the following classes:

```
public class Entity {
    public int Number { get; set; }
// Other methods, constructor etc, not relevant to this question.
}

public class Manager {
    private Foo() {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.Number = 1;
    }
}
```

On the line `entity.Number = 1`, I get the following compile time error:

```
 'Entity' does not contain a definition for 'Number' and no extension method 'Number accepting a first argument of type 'Entity' could be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I resolve this error? It seems like I should definitely be able to access the `Number` property.  I've tried doing it the non-auto property way as well. (i.e. I wrote a private backer variable and wrote out the get and set myself).

## **Edit**

Some helpful posters have advised me that I have not provided enough information.
My apologies, this is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow or similar sites.  Please see below for a more complete picture of the relevant code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using SharedContent;

namespace Glow
{
    public class GlowGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        // Viewport and graphics variables
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        public GlowGame()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            Entity entity = new Entity(Content);

            // Error occurs in line below!
            entity.Number = 1;
        }
        
        // Standard game template methods here:  Initialize, LoadContent, Update,
        // Draw, etc.

    }
}

in a separate file named Entity.


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace SharedContent
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public Entity(ContentManager content) { }
    }
}
```

Exact error message:

```
'SharedContent.Entity' does not contain a definition for 'Number' and no extension method 'Number' accepting a first argument of type 'SharedContent.Entity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Another note, I have checked and rechecked that `Entity` is in fact point at the correct code and not some other `Entity`.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a different Entity that Manager is refering to?

Comment: make sure those are in the same namespace

Comment: Good point @forsvarir, are these both in the same file?  What other namespaces does Manager reference?  Entity is kinda a fairly common name so you may be colliding.  If you look at the Intellisense for Entity it should tell you what namespace it's getting it from.

Comment: Aside from `Foo` not having a return type or being correctly named if it was intended to be the constructor then this should work. You are going to have to post a complete sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok more information:  
1.  They're in different namespaces but the name space that Manager has a reference to the namespace that Entity is in.
2.  @Brian, yes there should have been a return type.  In the program it's void.
3.  I'm pretty sure that it's not collision, I right clicked on the name and went to the definition -- it's the class I want.

Comment: So in other words, the scenario you're presenting in the question is very different from the scenario that repros the bug. That's not helpful when trying to diagnose the problem. Can you present the problem in a way that we can reproduce it?

Comment: @Eric Lippert You're right.  I didn't present it in the most helpful way originally.  I have edited the question above to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven’t tested it, I strongly suspect that if I copy and paste your code into Visual Studio, it will not produce the error you quoted. (Even your edited version.)

Please post an example that *actually produces the error*. Trim your project down to the bones and post just the bits that are relevant to the problem. In all likelihood, you will find the error in the process yourself :)

Comment: You were essentially right.  The issue was that I had another error (which I mistakenly thought was not relevant).  Once I resolved that error, my initial question was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your example it *should* work - could you verify that `Entity` points to the class you defined, and not some built-in class? (right-click `Entity` in Visual Studio, go to definition).